# Rails placeholder to form using formtag not working throwing runtime exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]Rails placeholder to form using formtag not working throwing runtime exception

below is the view:

```
  <%= form_tag({:action => 'login_attempt'}, {:class => 'ui large form'}) do %>
            <div class="ui stacked segment">

        <div class="field">
              <div class="ui left icon input">
                <i class="user icon"></i>
        <%= text_field_tag:email,placeholder: 'Email'%>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
              <div class="ui left icon input">
                <i class="lock icon"></i>
        <%= password_field_tag :login_password %>

        </div>
            </div>
        <%= submit_tag("Log In") %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is both a syntax error as previous answers have noted and you also must set the second parameter to `nil` or some value for placeholder to work

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: 'Email'%>
```

or if you need to set it to some value

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: 'Email' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between the tag and the label:

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, placeholder: 'Email'%>
```

Comment: getting email in value place not place holder check in images updated in question https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ndu.png

Answer (score 0):

This is Syntax Error. Correct your code.

```
<%= text_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: 'Email'%>
```

Comment: getting email in value place not place holder check in images updated in question https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ndu.png

Comment: Yes, we have to pass a value either nil or any value in params.

Answer (score 0):

add nil  as `<%= text_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: 'Email' %>`